# Javascript how to call overrided method from constructor

Tags: javascript

I have two classes in javascript a, b. Class b extends a. Class a calls method in constructor. I wanna override this method in b class. How to call overridable method? when I added to class a, to constructor this.method(), it always calls method from a class.

```js
class a {
  constructor() {
    this.method();
  }

  method() {
    alert("a");
  }
}

class b extends a {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  method() {
    alert("b");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
class A {
 constructor(){
  this.method()
}

 method(){
  alert("a");
}

}

class B extends A {
  constructor(){
    super()
  }

  method(){
    alert("b");
  }
}

new B();
```

Comment: How does uppercasing the class names answer the question?

Comment: actually uppercase is not doing any thing, just a convention to follow. Normal object with first letter as lowercase, class with first letter as uppercase.

Comment: I previously think that you miss the word, `extends`, which creates the issue. So I answer the question by having the keyword `extends`. Would you mind share which browser and version / node version you are using to have such abnormal case coming up.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know in advance whether the instance is of the subclass or superclass, you can make sure the superclass calls its own method by having the superclass reference itself explicitly:

```
A.prototype.method.call(this);
```

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    A.prototype.method.call(this);
  }

  method() {
    console.log("a");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  method() {
    console.log("b");
  }
}

const b = new B();
```